# Is it wrong to provide a scientific explanation to a question in Hinduism SE?

Tags: discussion

One of my answers in this SE has been commented that it is not permitted to provide an answer on the grounds of scientific reasoning.

I think that Religion compliments Science, so in my view a scientific reason behind a religious view makes sense.

Please do explain as to why it is not acceptable to give a scientific answer.

Comment: Its' been asked twice before on meta, [Refer here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/292/76) for answer